# If $A$ is normal matrix and $A$ has distinct eigenvalue and $AB=BA$.why $B$ is normal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is normal matrix and $A$ has distinct eigenvalue and $AB=BA$.why $B$ is normal?($A,B \in {M_n}$)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean that $A$ does not have any repeated eigen-values :

Let $D = UAU^{-1}, C = UBU^{-1}$, then
$$
DC = CD
$$
so we may assume that $A$ is diagonal. Now let $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_n\}$ be the standard basis, so that
$$
A(e_i) = \lambda_i e_i
$$
Then
$$
BA(e_1) = \lambda_i B(e_i) = AB(e_i)
$$
and so $B(e_i)$ is an eigen-vector with the same eigen-value. Since $A$ does not have any repeated eigen-values, $\exists \mu_i \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
B(e_i) = \mu_i e_i \quad
$$
This is true for each $i$, and so $B$ is a diagonal matrix, and so it must be normal.